scrollIntoView() displays "not a function" in jquery
I have an html class that has several dozen divs each of which have the crib-song-name css class. When one of those elements are clicked, I want the browser to scroll to the next element that has that class type.
$(".crib-song-name").click(function () {
    var next = $(this).parent().next().find(".crib-song-name");
    if (next) {
        next.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
});

The click() and find() functions appear to be finding the correct (i.e., next) element. However, the debugger reports that scrollIntoView is not a function on this line:
next.scrollIntoView(true);

Guidance? Thanks!

If you have several dozen matching divs, then next is going to be an array, and arrays do not have a "scrollIntoView" function.  Which ONE do you want scrolled in?

Post code as a [mcve] and include the HTML.

.scrollIntoView() is a JavaScript method and doesn't recognize jQuery object next as a DOM object. Try dereferencing the jQuery object by changing next into next[0] or next.get(0).

@zer00ne solved it. I needed to dereference next.

The solution, as stated in a comment by @zer00ne, was to dereference my next variable, i.e., change this:
next.scrollIntoView(true);

to this:
next[0].scrollIntoView(true);

